# Tool to visualize SQL Cascade tree

Tags: sql-server

Is there a tool that will let you visualize a SQL Server 2008 cascade tree?  I'm having troubles with items not being able to be deleted and I would like to see the path that SQL takes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/foreign+keys/69110/

if you don't want to give them an e-mail, here is the code:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ShowDeleteTree]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[ShowDeleteTree]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ShowDeleteTree
    @TableName varchar(128),
    @PrintDepth int = 9
AS  

-- print tree of dependencies for any table
declare 
    @p varchar(128),
    @c1 varchar(128),
    @c2 varchar(128),
    @c3 varchar(128),
    @c4 varchar(128),
    @c5 varchar(128),
    @c6 varchar(128),
    @c7 varchar(128),
    @delaction varchar(20),
    @char9 varchar(10)


set @p = @TableName
set @char9 = '-->'

-- view as text

-- hierarchy -------------------------------------------------------------
set nocount on
declare @loop int
declare @dep table( child varchar(100), parent varchar(100), pass int, delaction varchar(20))

-- dependency list
insert into @dep
select distinct object_name(parent_object_id), object_name(referenced_object_id), 0, delete_referential_action_desc
from sys.foreign_keys 
where parent_object_id <> referenced_object_id
order by 1,2



-- bottom: children that are never parents
update
    @dep
set
    pass = 1
where
    child not in 
        (
            select 
                parent
            from
                @dep
        )


-- middle to top: parents where children have been processed
set @loop = 2
while @loop < 10
begin
    update
        @dep
    set
        pass = @loop
    where
        pass = 0
    and
        parent in 
            (
                -- select parents where all children have been processed
                select
                    parent
                from
                    @dep d1
                where
                    pass = 0
                and
                    not exists
                        (select * from @dep d2 where d1.child=d2.parent and d2.pass=0)
            )

    set @loop = @loop + 1
end

select parent as 'ImmediateParent', delaction as 'DeleteAction' from @dep where child = @p
print ''

print '-- children of'
print @p

if exists (select * 
from sys.tables t join sys.triggers tr on t.object_id=tr.parent_id 
where t.name = @p
and tr.is_instead_of_trigger=1
and objectproperty(tr.object_id,'ExecIsDeleteTrigger')=1)
    print 'Has "Instead Of Delete" Trigger so parents cannot cascade delete it.

'


--1
select @c1=min(child) from @dep where parent = @p
while @c1 is not null
begin
    select @delaction = delaction from @dep where child=@c1 and parent=@p
    if @printdepth >=1 print @char9+@c1+' '+@delaction
    --2
    select @c2=min(child) from @dep where parent = @c1
    while @c2 is not null
    begin
        select @delaction = delaction from @dep where child=@c2 and parent=@c1
        if @printdepth >=2 print @char9+@char9+@c2+' '+@delaction
        --3
        select @c3=min(child) from @dep where parent = @c2
        while @c3 is not null
        begin
            select @delaction = delaction from @dep where child=@c3 and parent=@c2
            if @printdepth >=3 print @char9+@char9+@char9+@c3+' '+@delaction
            --4
            select @c4=min(child) from @dep where parent = @c3
            while @c4 is not null
            begin
                select @delaction = delaction from @dep where child=@c4 and parent=@c3
                if @printdepth >=4 print @char9+@char9+@char9+@char9+@c4+' '+@delaction
                --5
                select @c5=min(child) from @dep where parent = @c4
                while @c5 is not null
                begin
                    select @delaction = delaction from @dep where child=@c5 and parent=@c4
                    if @printdepth >=5 print @char9+@char9+@char9+@char9+@char9+@c5+' '+@delaction
                    --6
                    select @c6=min(child) from @dep where parent = @c5
                    while @c6 is not null
                    begin
                        select @delaction = delaction from @dep where child=@c6 and parent=@c5
                        if @printdepth >=6 print @char9+@char9+@char9+@char9+@char9+@char9+@c6+' '+@delaction
                        --7
                        select @c7=min(child) from @dep where parent = @c6
                        while @c7 is not null
                        begin
                            select @delaction = delaction from @dep where child=@c7 and parent=@c6
                            if @printdepth >=7 print @char9+@char9+@char9+@char9+@char9+@char9+@char9+@c7+' '+@delaction
                            select @c7=min(child) from @dep where parent = @c6 and child > @c7
                        end
                        --7
                        select @c6=min(child) from @dep where parent = @c5 and child > @c6
                    end
                    --6
                    select @c5=min(child) from @dep where parent = @c4 and child > @c5
                end
                --5
                select @c4=min(child) from @dep where parent = @c3 and child > @c4
            end
            --4
            select @c3=min(child) from @dep where parent = @c2 and child > @c3
        end
        --3
        select @c2=min(child) from @dep where parent = @c1 and child > @c2
    end
    --2
    select @c1=min(child) from @dep where parent = @p and child > @c1
end
--1

return 0
GO
```