# Visualize SQL (Oracle) cascade delete tree

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to visualize (doesn't have to be fancy) the cascade delete path/tree of a database that I'm analyzing. I'm having trouble getting an overview of the path taken when deleting a single row in a specific table.

The solution I'm looking for would be similar to [Tool to visualize SQL Cascade tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404555/tool-to-visualize-sql-cascade-tree) but then for an Oracle DB.

Does anyone know of a good tool or script to help me with this?

I'm currently working with SQL Developer, so if there's a solution within the tool, I would be glad to hear it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you could use is the ER diagram to see how the FKs correlate to the table you are starting from and the cascading tables so forth.

Although I use SQL Dev I had to actually search for this option, its pretty hidden as compared to other IDEs.

File → Data Modeler → Import → Data Dictionary → select DB connection

EDIT:

```
SELECT   uc.constraint_name||CHR(10)
||      '('||ucc1.TABLE_NAME||'.'||ucc1.column_name||')' constraint_source
,       'REFERENCES'||CHR(10)
||      '('||ucc2.TABLE_NAME||'.'||ucc2.column_name||')' references_column
FROM     dba_constraints uc
,        dba_cons_columns ucc1
,        dba_cons_columns ucc2
WHERE    uc.constraint_name = ucc1.constraint_name
AND      uc.r_constraint_name = ucc2.constraint_name
AND      ucc1.POSITION = ucc2.POSITION -- Correction for multiple column primary keys.
AND      uc.constraint_type = 'R'
AND      uc.delete_rule = 'CASCADE'
ORDER BY ucc1.TABLE_NAME
,        uc.constraint_name;
```

Sources: 
-http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2009/03/05/validating-foreign-keys/
-Myself

Comment: Appreciate the answer, since it is a nice view that gives me at least a better overview. It isn't a direct answer to the question though (I can't actually see the cascading path asked for), so I will wait for an even better solution to emerge. If this doesn't happen, I'll gladly accept your answer...

Comment: Rereading your comment and question... you'd be looking for a script that given a certain (Row?), you'd get the depending rows in other tables?

Comment: Well, I have specific delete on cascade statements for certain keys in tables, which I would like to see in a relational diagram to follow the cascading delete path (and I don't see them in the ER diagram; or am I doing something or looking wrong?).

Comment: A delete on cascade basically takes the row you are deleting and deletes also every dependent row that it may have in any other table. The row dependency is given by the foreign key constraints between tables (Thats what you should be seeing in the ER diagram). So, if you have a table A which has two tables with FKs referencing TO it (table B and table C) the ER diagram will show them as such graphically. Then if you delete on cascade from A you can assume it May delete any dependent row from those tables, tou could find them by taking the FK and seeing which is the related field on each table

Comment: Agreed, and I understand that. But...a FK isn't always cascade on delete. Might also be NO ACTION or SET NULL (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15276_01/doc.20/e13677/data_modeling.htm). Is there a way to see that in the ER diagram? If so, this is indeed an optimal solution.

Comment: I added a script that may work for you from the given source, added the cascade rule, it is obviously not graphical but it may give you a hand. You may need to replace the dba_ views for the user_ views of the same name.

Comment: Thanks @dElo, the ER diagram + script provide the means necessary, though I had hoped that there was a more visual way to just see the cascading path (implemented by Oracle/SQL Developer). Thanks for your effort and solution!